# Passing command line arguments through a C setuid wrapper to another script

Tags: c, perl, wrapper

I have the following c setuid wrapper:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>

main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    struct passwd *pwd;
    char user[] = "cvmfs-test";

    pwd = getpwnam(user);

    setuid(pwd->pw_uid);
    system(argv[1]);
}
```

I can call my perl script with `./cwrapper perlscript.pl`.

I would like to do `./cwrapper perlscript.pl --option1 --option2 --option3` and elaborate all arguments inside the perl script with GetOptions. How should I change my wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version dealing with a variable number of arguments. Please note that your syscalls should be tested to ensure everything is going OK.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pwd.h>

#define CMDMAXLGTH 4096
#define SETUIDUSER "testuser"

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
  struct passwd *pwd;
  char user[] = SETUIDUSER;
  char buf[CMDMAXLGTH];
  char *p = buf;
  int i = 1;

  pwd = getpwnam(user);
  // success test needed here 
  setuid(pwd->pw_uid);
  // success test needed here 

  memset (buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
  while (argv[i]) {
    p += sprintf(p, " %s", argv[i++]);
  }
  system(buf);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: See mpu's solution which is way better. Why bother with system when you exit right after it anyway. You save a fork and a shell and a lot of potential problems.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a nice solution which does not need any allocation, is able to deal with arbitrary long commands and does not imply running useless processes because it does not use `system`. Moreover with the following solution you get the exit code of the spawned process for free.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pwd.h>

#define SETUIDUSER "foobar"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct passwd *pwd;
  char user[] = SETUIDUSER;

  pwd = getpwnam(user);
  // success test needed here 
  setuid(pwd->pw_uid);
  // success test needed here 

  if (argc < 2)
    return 1;

  execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
  return 42;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sprintf` to build a character string with your options, then pass this string to system:

```
 char command [100];
 sprintf (command, "./cwrapper %s --%s --%s --%s", program_name,option1,option2,
     option3);
 system(command);
```

Update: this approach assumes a fixed number of arguments, and looking back at your question, I see that may not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the argv[0] because is the name of the c program and use all the other. You can calculate (`strlen`) the required memory to assemble a new string, `malloc()` the memory for the new string and then build your new string by concatenating all the `argv` (`strcat`). Or for a fixed length approach, follow @dan1111 answer.